# Histogram from single column in datafile

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can read in the following data and display a histogram of the frequency? I also want to add the labels 'WIN' and 'LOSS' (i.e. 0 and 1) and display the count above each bar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Period,Subject,Result,Direction
1,1,0,0
2,1,0,0
3,1,1,0
4,1,0,1
5,1,0,0
1,2,1,1
2,2,1,1
3,2,1,1
4,2,0,0
5,2,0,0
1,3,1,0
2,3,1,1
3,3,0,0
4,3,1,1
5,3,0,0
1,4,0,0
2,4,1,1
3,4,0,0
4,4,0,0
5,4,0,0
1,5,0,1
2,5,0,1
3,5,0,1
4,5,1,1
5,5,0,0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
%Period,Subject,Result,Direction

                \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[
                symbolic x coords={0,1},
                xtick=data,
ylabel=Participants,
                enlarge x limits=0.40,
                ]
\addplot[ybar,fill=gray] table [        
col sep=comma,
x=Direction,
    ] {data.csv};
                \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I was able to get this to work when I just had one or two columns in the data.csv file, but it doesn't once I need to select columns from it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what the desired output is. Do you just want two bars, one for the number of rows where Direction=0 and one for the number of rows where Direction=1?

Comment: For this MWE, yes. Just two bars, but I want to label the x-axis 'WIN' and 'LOSS' for 1 and 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the histogram, remove the `symbolic x coords` and set

```
hist = {
    bins = 2,
    data min = 0,
    data max = 2
}
```

in the `\addplot` options.

To add the labels on the axis, set

```
xtick = {0,1},
xticklabels = {Loss, Win}
```

in the `axis` options.

To get the data labels on top of the bars, set

```
nodes near coords
```

in the `axis` options and

```
intervals = false,
handler/.style = {ybar}
```

in the `hist` options and

```
bar direction = y,
bar width = 1
```

in the `\addplot` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.11}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
Period,Subject,Result,Direction
1,1,0,0
2,1,0,0
3,1,1,0
4,1,0,1
5,1,0,0
1,2,1,1
2,2,1,1
3,2,1,1
4,2,0,0
5,2,0,0
1,3,1,0
2,3,1,1
3,3,0,0
4,3,1,1
5,3,0,0
1,4,0,0
2,4,1,1
3,4,0,0
4,4,0,0
5,4,0,0
1,5,0,1
2,5,0,1
3,5,0,1
4,5,1,1
5,5,0,0
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel = Participants,
    enlarge x limits = 1,
    xtick = {0,1},
    xticklabels = {Loss, Win},
    ymin = 0,
    nodes near coords,
    xtick pos = left
]
\addplot[
    fill=gray,
    hist = {
        bins = 2,
        data min = 0,
        data max = 2,
        intervals = false,
        handler/.style = {ybar},
    },
    bar direction = y,
    bar width = 1
] table [        
    col sep = comma,
    y = Direction,
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```